# Threaded Comments Feature not working

Tags: comment-form, comments, theme-thesis

If a reader posts a comment on my blog, I'm able to reply to it. But the reply is not appearing on the post page, even after approving the comment. Number of comments to that specific post is 3, i.e., 2 from Readers + 1 Mine(Reply). Here is the example: http://www.gadgetcage.com/most-expensive-computers-in-the-world/16264/comment-page-1/#comment-65580 .

Note: I have enabled Threaded Comments. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple potential issues:

1. Your version of WordPress and/or your current Theme does not support threaded comments.

   - *What version of WordPress are you using?*
   - *What Theme are you using?*
2. Something is interfering with comment display

   - *What Plugins are you using, that might be interacting with comments?* These would include anti-spam Plugins, security Plugins, comment-related Plugins, etc.